# Creating and defining a family of functions with indexed variables?

Tags: function-construction, indexed-variable

I am trying to do the following: Create a list as

```
Table[Subscript[\[Beta], i] _, {i, 1, dim}]
```

And then use this list to define a function:

```
F[Table[Subscript[\[Beta], i] _, {i, 1, dim}]] := something in term of beta_i
```

But this is not working. My main objective is to define and use a family of functions in terms of $\{\beta_1 ,\dots , \beta_n\}$ like $F_1(\{b_1,\dots ,\beta_n\}), \dots ,F_m(\{b_1,\dots ,\beta_n\})$.

How can I do that?

Comment: why not `F[i_][vars_]:=...` ?

Comment: Subscript is not a valid pattern name. Instead of $\{b_1,b_2,\ldots\}$ why not use `b` as the name of a vector. You can use then `b[[1]]`, `b[[2]]`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, you can't define functions inside Table or a Do loop. Unless there is a hack to do it.

> My main objective is to define and use a family of functions

Why not define the function `F` itself to take its id as part of the definition?  As a meta function. Like this

```
F[i_,Subscript[β_,i_],Subscript[b_,i_]]:=Subscript[β,i]+i+i*Subscript[b,i]
```

And now, if you wan to call $F_2$ for example, you do

```
i = 2;
F[i, Subscript[β, i], Subscript[b, i]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to make different definitions for each `$F_i`, depending on the value of `i`, you can do something like this

```
F[i_Integer, Subscript[β_, i_], Subscript[b_, i_]] := Module[{},
  Which[i == 1, Subscript[β, i] + i + i*Subscript[b, i],
   i == 2, Subscript[β, i] + 3*i - i*2*Subscript[b, i]
   (*add more F_i special definitions here*)
   ]
  ]
```

Which looks like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now can do

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and so on. btw, the sooner you avoid subscripted variable, the better it is. I never found any use for them and they cause more trouble than worth it.

Comment: Yeah. I've managed to do the following: I generate the following list `g = Table[ToExpression[(Alphabet[][[k]]) <> "_"], {k, 1, dim}];` and then I use this to declare a funcion f[g]:=...``

Comment: Ah, I discovered I can create an endless supply of variables with `q[x_]:=(x<>"_");ToExpression/@(q/@(StringJoin/@Drop[Subsets[Alphabet[],2],1]))`